# Use a struct in place of a primitive for a EF4 property type

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

I've got an EF4 entity (code-first) that includes an int bitmask. I've created a Bitmask struct to make working with bitmasks easier (provides bool properties to access the bits). The bitmask struct includes overloaded implicit operators for converting to and from an int.

I tried setting the property type to the bitmask struct but the value is coming back as 0. I know the value in the database has a value and the bitmask works in my unit tests. I set the HasColumnType to "INT".

The property...

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Display Pages Bitmask")]
[Column(Name = "fDisplayPagesBitmask")]
public DisplayPagesBitmask DisplayPagesBitmask { get; set; }
```

From the context object...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Website>()
        .Property(m => m.DisplayPagesBitmask)
        .HasColumnType("INT");
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: This is possible with ef-core 8. Take a look at my answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956158/how-to-flatten-a-struct-inside-an-object-to-a-database-in-entity-framework/77811203#77811203 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600685/decomposing-structs-in-ef-core/77811218#77811218

Answer (score 4):

You can't map your structure directly. You have to map int property (make setter internal or protected) and provide second non mapped property (use `NotMappedAttribute` or `Ignore` method) of your custom type which internally sets mapped integer property.

Comment: Any news on this subject? I have a struct-type property that encapsulates a plain int. Anything changed since 2013?

Comment: yes also looking for how you go from class to structs

Answer (score 0):

I used a calculated property `struct` to get to the properties which works with SQLite in Entity Framework 6.
Access modifier protected for the `ForSQLite` properties did not work for me. Even though they should be private or protected in my eyes.

```
    public Boolean ZystostatikaForSQLite {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Boolean ImmunsupressivaForSQLite {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Boolean AntikoagolanzienForSQLite {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Boolean GlucokortikoideForSQLite {
        get;
        set;
    }
    // 4 Kategorien der Arzneimittel: Zytostatika, Immunsupressiva, Antikoagolanzien, Glucokortikoide
    public struct PharmaceuticalCategories {
        public Boolean Zystostatika;
        public Boolean Immunsupressiva;
        public Boolean Antikoagolanzien;
        public Boolean Glucokortikoide;
    };
    public PharmaceuticalCategories medicineTaken {
        get {
            PharmaceuticalCategories pc = new PharmaceuticalCategories();
            pc.Zystostatika = this.ZystostatikaForSQLite;
            pc.Immunsupressiva = this.ImmunsupressivaForSQLite;
            pc.Antikoagolanzien = this.AntikoagolanzienForSQLite;
            pc.Glucokortikoide = this.GlucokortikoideForSQLite;

            return pc;
        }
        set {
            this.ZystostatikaForSQLite = value.Zystostatika;
            this.ImmunsupressivaForSQLite = value.Immunsupressiva;
            this.AntikoagolanzienForSQLite = value.Antikoagolanzien;
            this.GlucokortikoideForSQLite = value.Glucokortikoide;
        }
    }
```