# Work-around for Struct with Entity Framework, Code-First approach

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm currently constructing a database from an existing system with EF and code-first approach.

It is preferred that minimal changes is made to the 'core' classes.
Because of this I would like to find a work-around for Structs and EF.

Is it possible to wrap a Struct into a class in any way so that EF can use the data within this Struct? Since EF are able to create its own Proxies of my 'core' classes, shouldn't I be able to this as well?

My knowledge about .Net, C# and EF is rather limited because I started to learn this language this year due to a bachelor assignment.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: Added examplecode.

Core has many classes that utilizes the TaxMode Struct, and store data in this Struct.

```
public class AcmeClass
{    
TaxMode Taxmode { get; set; }
}
```

The Struct is as follows:

```
public struct TaxMode
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public bool isTrue { get; set; }
}
```

Any attempt to add the properties of `TaxMode` into those classes only result in non-nullable errors.

Comment: was it helpful for you?

Comment: @MikroDel I'm thinking how I can implement that class into the existing system without changing the Struct to Class, something I would rather not do.

Comment: This is possible with ef-core 8. Take a look at my answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956158/how-to-flatten-a-struct-inside-an-object-to-a-database-in-entity-framework/77811203#77811203 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600685/decomposing-structs-in-ef-core/77811218#77811218

Answer (score 8):

Structs are not supported.

You have to use `class` istead of it.

*Updated*

take a look at this [Ladislav Mrnka answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678158/502950)

Comment: Isn't there a way to wrap the Struct into a class in runtime or compilation with reflection or something?

Comment: I didn't get the approach in the link to work. Might just have to do a dirty fix here, and add the structs data as properties into those classes which uses this struct.

Comment: @JonasBG - to add a struct as a propertie is a good idea. And it will work - if you can really add your structure in your class. After your comments I thought you cannot make any changes in your code. The other way it will be not a big difference to rename struct in a class or to build a struct into another class.

Comment: how I understand it, that example stores an int in the database, which then is populated into an Struct. My way is the other way around. I have a Struct that stores data. And I want these data to be stored in the database. I'm grateful that you are taking your time to help me, though I'm not completely confident with C# code and approaches yet =)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered serialization as below?

```cs
[NotMapped]
public TaxMode? TaxMode { get; set; }
public string TaxModeJSON
{
    get
    {
        return TaxMode == null
                   ? null
                   : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TaxMode);
    }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            TaxMode = null;
        else
            TaxMode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaxMode>(value);
    }
}
```

that solution will save your struct as JSON and use serialization to store and retrieve data to/from database.