# Decomposing structs in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have the following class:

```
struct Vector
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
}

class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Vector Position { get; set; }
}
```

How do I configure that in Entity Framework (core) such that it maps to Name, PositionX, PositionY, PositionZ?

This is for code generation purposes, so I don't want the user having to create their POCO's with EF in mind (it emits to a whole lot of other languages too!)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For Entity Framework Core what you're describing are called [owned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

And the configuration is something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
    .OwnsOne(p => p.Position);
```

Comment: `error CS0452: The type 'Vector' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TRelatedEntity' in the generic type or method 'EntityTypeBuilder<Player>.OwnsOne<TRelatedEntity>(Expression<Func<Player, TRelatedEntity>>)'`

Answer (score 3):

Currently (EF Core 3) it is not supported. However, there is a GitHub issue about it and looks like structs-as-owned-types has been accepted for future versions:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9906

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the same thing, and came across this question. Thought I'd post what I found: The EF Core team suggest to store it as JSON in your database and use a custom value convertor:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Property(e => e.Vector)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Vector>(v, null));
```

Not ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with ef-core 8. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew) is a link to the whatsnew-page, where you can find a full explanation for the feature as well as some guidance to choose the right types. This seems to be a very important point. Take a look at `records`, especially `record struct` or the immutable `readonly record struct` to be sure to choose the best implementation.

If your type is a class, you can annotate it for db-configuration:

```
[ComplexType]
public class SomeClass
{
    ...
}
```

However this doesn't apply on records, structs etc. For these types you have to use FluentApi:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Player>().ComplexProperty(e=>e.Position);
}
```

By default this implementation results in a table `Player` with following columns:

```
Name | Position_X | Position_Y | Position_Z
```

If you want to configure the columns of Vector you can do something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Player>().ComplexProperty(e=>e.Position, b=> 
    {
        b.Property(p=>p.X).HasColumnType("whatever");
        ....
    });
}
```