# How to flatten a struct inside an object to a database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a `class A` that contains a `struct B` and some data.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id      { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public B MyB       { get; set; }
}

public struct B
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    public int Var2 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to serialize `A` to a MySql database using Entity Framework. I would like each row to look like

```
Id | Name | MyB_Var1 | MyB_Var2
```

I know I can achieve this by changing B to be a class and marking it `[Owned]`, but I'd like to keep it a struct.
Can I do this, maybe by providing a way to map the internal members to database columns? Is there a way I can specify the mapping to flatten it into the `OnModelCreating()` function of my `DbContext`? Thanks

Comment: Could you set the property MyB as `string` instead of `B`? In the program you'd use the struct `B`, then serialize it as json before writing to the database.

Comment: That would mean I'd have a string column in my database, which prevents running queries against it, so I'd prefer one column per B variable.

Comment: Entity requires the c# classes to map into the database.  You need an interface that would take your classes and map a c# class with four properties.

Comment: @GertArnold B is an existing struct used across the codebase with the assumption it has value semantics, not reference ones. Changing it to a class would break that and require a lot of changes.

Comment: @jdweng you mean having an interface that maps the struct to a class? That could work. Do you know how could one go about to do it?

Comment: At the moment this is not supported (see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9906), you could use a struct and store it as a string in the db (by serializing it as json with a conversion) but you wouldn't be able to query its properties. Or you could create a mirror, owned class with the same properties, which will get mapped as you want it, you could query its properties, and then you could use a NotMapped property of your struct type to get/set the underlying class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, mentioned in the comments of the question is resolved with ef-core 8. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew) is a link to the whatsnew-page of ef-core 8, where you can find a full explanation for the feature as well as some guidance to choose the right types. This seems to be a very important point. Take a look at `records`, especially `record struct` or the immutable `readonly record struct` to be sure to choose the best implementation.

If your type is a class, you can annotate it for db-configuration:

```
[ComplexType]
public class B
{
    ...
}
```

However this doesn't apply on records, structs etc. For these types you have to use FluentApi:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<A>().ComplexProperty(e=>e.B);
}
```

By default this implementation results in a table `A` with following columns:

```
Id | Name | B_Var1 | B_Var2
```

If you want to configure the columns of B you can do something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<A>().ComplexProperty(e=>e.B, b=> 
    {
        b.Property(p=>p.Var1).HasColumnType("whatever");
        ....
    });
}
```